# Boost assign list_of for a structure

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have a question regarding the boost::assign_list

```
struct AClass{
AClass();
};

struct BClass{
BClass();
};

typedef AInfo{
   string infoname;
   AClass m_nAClass;
   BClass m_nBClass;
};

typedef list<AInfo> listOfAInfo;

listOfAInfo m_mlistOfAInfo =
     boost::assign::list_of("AInfoName1", AClass(), BClass() );
```

How do I initialise the array of map_lists for the structs. This is a version of the legacy code, where the some classes are defined as structs with the constructors.

thanks,
pdk

Comment: What does _"where the some classes are defined as structs with the constructors."_ mean?

Comment: `map_list_of` doesn't match `list<AInfo>`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of

Comment: thanks sehe, yes you are correct. I meant list_of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what *"where the some classes are defined as structs with the constructors"* means.

What I see is aggregates, which can be initialized with aggregate initializer syntax even in C++03 (or C++98 IIRC):

```
AInfo obj = { "AInfoName1", AClass(), BClass() };
```

Perhaps you can just use

```
typedef std::map<int, AInfo> listOfAInfo;

listOfAInfo m_mlistOfAInfo =
    boost::assign::map_list_of
        ( 1, { "AInfoName1", AClass(), BClass() })
        ( 2, { "AInfoName2", AClass(), BClass() });
```

or

```
typedef std::list<AInfo> listOfAInfo;

listOfAInfo m_mlistOfAInfo =
    boost::assign::list_of
        ( AInfo { "AInfoName1", AClass(), BClass() })
        ( AInfo { "AInfoName2", AClass(), BClass() });
```

Here it is **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e48429fd5cb63d35)** (c++11).

It does seem that you cannot use the uniform initiliazation syntax (`AInfo {...}`) which is subtly different from an aggregate initializer `= { ... }`) with Boost Assign, because the compiler doesn't know what you're initializing, unlike the `obj` declaration shown above.

Comment: Thanks Sehe:tried similar solution. But getting error: expected primary-expression before '{' token, on the line boost::assign::list_of
        ( AInfo { } ). When tried to replace the AInfo with char, and tried as listofu8s m_mlist = boost::assign::list_of(u8{1});, also get the similar error. But when replaced with m_mlist = boost::assign::list_of(1); the error is not seen. Typecasting is creating the issue i think

Comment: That's for the reason I explained. I guess you'll need to add that constructor or use a factory function

Comment: Added the constructor , but doesnot compile :( . Have you compiled the code you posted on Coliru ?

Comment: @pdk Coliru compiles it online, that's what it's for. Note it says c++11. Here's what I meant in my precvious comment: **[_LIVE_ On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbead3fca8f6d2d0)**

Comment: And this [with a *factory function*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd37331e14f0fc16) instead.